# ChartJS only show me data when I zoom-in or zoom-out

Tags: javascript, chart.js

actually I'm using ASP.NET with SQL Server. And I'm using ChartJS to do the Charts for my Website. The problem is that ChartJS only show me the results when I do zoom in or zoom out in the browser.

Anyone knows why?, I'm using AJAX to get information from the Database and do a dynamic Chart.

This is my JavaScript:

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST", 
            url: "Graficas.asmx/obtenerGrafica",
            data: '',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json", // dataType is json format
            success: function OnSuccess(response) {
                items = response.d;
                $.each(items, function (index, val) {
                    myChart.data.labels.push(val.Nombre);
                    myChart.data.datasets[0].data.push(val.Gastado);
                    nmbre.push(val.Nombre);
                    precio.push(val.Gastado);
                });
            },
            error: function onError(error) {
                console.log(error.d);
            },
        });
        var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'horizontalBar',
            data: {
                labels: [],
                datasets: [{
                    label: ['Mensual'],
                    data: [],
                    backgroundColor: [
                        'rgba(137, 107, 255, 0.3)'
                    ],
                    borderColor: [
                        'rgba(137, 107, 255, 1)',

                    ],
                    borderWidth: 1
                }
                ]
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero: true
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        });           
    });
```

Thank u.

Comment: Kindly any know answer of below questions, let me know https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67979157/chartjs-line-diagram-interface-with-database-also-need-zoom-reset-zoom-in-zoo

Answer (score 0):

Try calling your ajax method after initializing the chart object.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'horizontalBar',
        data: {
            labels: [],
            datasets: [{
                label: ['Mensual'],
                data: [],
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(137, 107, 255, 0.3)'
                ],
                borderColor: [
                    'rgba(137, 107, 255, 1)',

                ],
                borderWidth: 1
            }
            ]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    });  
$.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        url: "Graficas.asmx/obtenerGrafica",
        data: '',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json", // dataType is json format
        success: function OnSuccess(response) {
            items = response.d;
            $.each(items, function (index, val) {
                myChart.data.labels.push(val.Nombre);
                myChart.data.datasets[0].data.push(val.Gastado);
                nmbre.push(val.Nombre);
                precio.push(val.Gastado);
            });
        },
        error: function onError(error) {
            console.log(error.d);
        },
    });         
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add two arrays before your ajax call:

```
var nomreArr= [];
var gastadoArr= [];
```

Then populate them in the success function 
and then assign them to the datasets

```
nomreArr.push(val.Nombre);
gastadoArr.push(val.Gastado);

myChart.data.datasets[0].data = gastadoArr;
myChart.data.datasets[0].labels= nomreArr;
myChart.update();
```

also your HTML should be like:

`<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="150"></canvas>`

Answer (score 0):

I had his same exact issue, and the only way I was able to fix it was by adding the following just before closing the document.ready block:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    myChart.update();
},1000);
```

It's less than ideal but that was the only thing I could do to consistently get the chart to render -- call the "update" method after a 1 second delay.